# Implementing PHP password_hash() in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm performing a Database Export operation from MSSQL to MYSSQL datatbase.
My MSSQL DB is having its Table '**tbl_users**' with a password field (plain passsword, say 12345678).

But my corresponding MYSQL DB, with table 'tbl_users' is using passwords generated from password_hash() encryption.

So how can I build `password_hash()` method in MSSQL?

If further explained, How can i convert '12345678'(plain text) to '$2y$10$krhNlFVvZ2WAPRNCdHEPOOM9RQZEjSVVPhXlW3kKuLpraFVjlEzvO'(using `password_hash()`)?

Comment: Take the function source code and translate it.

Comment: Sorry. You mean to translate the source code of password_hash() to SQL query?

Comment: You could call an equivalent .NET function using SQL CLR, [example here](http://blog.tcs.de/using-the-bcrypt-hash-algorithm-in-ms-sql-server/)

Comment: @Andomar's SQL CLR Method works perfectly fine. Thank very much (for your solution, and also for letting me to know about SQL CLR funtionality)

Comment: @Andomar: Can you please make this as an answer to this question, so that I can make this as answered (Sorry if I'm bothering you too much)?

Comment: Are you sure `HASHBYTES` doesn't do what you want? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx. This is much less invasive then turning on CLR

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: As per the example "$2a$" is the Algorithm extension , "10$"  is the  cost, "v16Jn78diXK/pHSYWBzMM."  is the  salt generated and "IeN5Ooi3gDQyxj8sxsv8WMeCUoJK1ya" id the  hashed password.  But SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'weakPassword1234') gives me only 0x410633E488C4116DA24F559C54CB753BFEB7996B

Comment: Since my Mysql DB is already taking values after the PHP operation `password_hash()`, I'm forced to do the same with MSSQL also. SO @Andomar 's solution fulfill my needs

Comment: OK, sounds like the SQL function can't do what you want. Primarily I'm suggesting you understand the ramifications of introducing CLR to your system. The two main issues are: 1. Some SQL DBA's don't allow CLR in their production servers, 2. Performance is usually poor. If they aren't issues then seems like a decent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call an equivalent .NET function using SQL CLR, [example here](http://blog.tcs.de/using-the-bcrypt-hash-algorithm-in-ms-sql-server/).